# How does Microsoft Storport work with SATA legacy mode?

Tags: windows, winapi, driver

I have a driver designed in Storport-miniport model. I'm trying to modify the driver to support SATA legacy mode. Here are some questions which I am looking for help:

1. the I/O Address

   In Native mode, the IO address is shown in BAR0 to BAR3. But in legacy mode, the IO address is fixed(0x1f0 for command, 0x3f6 for control in channel-0). In native mode, we used StorPortGetDeviceBase to get the memory-map of the IO address, but it doesn't work with legacy mode since Storport could only handle the IO space announced in PCI space. Therefore, I tried to use MmMapIoSpace to allocate memories. Is this a correct way?
2. The IRQ

   Just like IO Address, IRQ is fix for legacy mode. But the whole thing about IRQ is done by Storport, should I or could I do anything here?
3. the HwStorInitialize does not called

   MSDN says HwStorInitialize should be called if HwStorFindAdapter return true. But in my driver with legacy mode, the HwStorInitialize does not called so the adapter in device manager shows not ready with yellow mark. Did I miss something?
4. ATAport-minoport

   When I was trying to figure out those problems, I found there's another driver mode called ATAport-miniport. Does this mean I should design my driver in the model if my adapter is in legacy mode? Is it possible to implement legacy mode in the same driver as native mode by Storport-miniport?